# let $S=\{ \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}:m,n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$. then $S$ is compact set in $\mathbb{R}$. True or False.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

let $S=\{ \frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}:m,n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{0\}$.

then $S$ is compact set in $\mathbb{R}$. True or False.

since derived set of $S=\{\frac{1}{n}:n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup\{0\}$ . and this is not a subset of $S$. Hence $S$ is not closed set and not compact set in $\mathbb{R}$

But in my book it is given to compact .Is my argument valid ?

Comment: What is a 'derived' set?

Comment: How do you know that the derived set is not a subset? Which element of the derived set is not in $S$?

Comment: @Keen-amateur The set of all limit points.

Comment: Why $\left \{\frac 1 n : n \in \Bbb N  \right \} \cup \{0 \}$ is not a subset of $S$? Observe that $\frac 1 n = \frac {1} {2n} + \frac {1} {2n}.$

Comment: note that $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}$ so it is a subset of $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and this is not a subset of $S$.

What makes you think so? Note that every (nonzero) element of the derived set can be written as $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}$ and hence it belongs to $S$.

So $S$ actually **is** closed. And so it is compact because it is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

$S$ is obviously bounded, and it is closed because $\operatorname{acc}(S)=\{1/m\,|\,m\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}\subset S$, so it is compact by Bolzano's theorem.